# Edit/update from activerecords "unpermited params"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app that can allow proprietaire(name of user) to edit their campings(nome of post). Post have proprietaire_id. This part works.

I added some details on the camping (piscine, barbecue) in another table name caracteristiquetest. I made a relationship with camping_id. I can display value for piscine and barbecue. But when i try to allow proprietaire(user) to edit/update their camping, record not save and i have an error unpermited params.

How can i do this ?

Sorry for my english im french

camping_controller.rb

```
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @camping.update(camping_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @camping, notice: 'Camping was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @camping }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @camping.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
  def camping_params
      params.require(:camping).permit(:name, :adresse, :code_postale, :commune, :courriel, :site_internet, :tel, :description, :nomdep, :nomregion, :numdep, :slug, :ville_id, :region_id, :departement_id, :latitude, :longitude, :etoile, :user_id, :image)
      params.require(:caracteristiquetest).permit(:piscine, :barbecue)
    end
```

camping.rb

```
belongs_to :proprietaire
belongs_to :caracteristiquetest
accepts_nested_attributes_for :caracteristiquetest
```

caracteristiquetest.rb

```
class Caracteristiquetest < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :camping
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :camping
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.select(:piscine, [['Non renseigné',"Non renseigné"], ['Oui',"Oui"], ['Non',"Non"]], {:selected => (@camping.caracteristiquetest.piscine?)}, {class:"form-control", id:"exampleSelect1"}) %>
```

**EDIT**
development.log

```
  Started GET "/campings/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-28 14:06:56 +0200
Processing by CampingsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mCamping Load (1719.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "campings".* FROM "campings" WHERE "campings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "campings".* FROM "campings" WHERE "campings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering campings/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mCaracteristiquetest Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "caracteristiquetests".* FROM "caracteristiquetests" WHERE "caracteristiquetests"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mProprietaire Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "proprietaires".* FROM "proprietaires" WHERE "proprietaires"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCamping Load (1900.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT campings.*, (69.09332411348201 * ABS(campings.latitude - 48.52566299999999) * 0.7071067811865475) + (59.836573914187355 * ABS(campings.longitude - 3.664031) * 0.7071067811865475) AS distance, CASE WHEN (campings.latitude >= 48.52566299999999 AND campings.longitude >= 3.664031) THEN  45.0 WHEN (campings.latitude <  48.52566299999999 AND campings.longitude >= 3.664031) THEN 135.0 WHEN (campings.latitude <  48.52566299999999 AND campings.longitude <  3.664031) THEN 225.0 WHEN (campings.latitude >= 48.52566299999999 AND campings.longitude <  3.664031) THEN 315.0 END AS bearing FROM "campings" WHERE (campings.latitude BETWEEN 48.38093121688914 AND 48.67039478311084 AND campings.longitude BETWEEN 3.445496852835473 AND 3.8825651471645273 AND campings.id != 1) ORDER BY distance ASC[0m
  [1m[36mProprietaire Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "proprietaires".* FROM "proprietaires" WHERE "proprietaires"."id" = ? ORDER BY "proprietaires"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered campings/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2184.1ms)
  Rendered campings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (19341.1ms)
  Rendered devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_nav.html.erb (100.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
  [1m[36mProprietaire Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "proprietaires".* FROM "proprietaires" WHERE "proprietaires"."id" = ? ORDER BY "proprietaires"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/partials/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8799ms (Views: 1524.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3620.2ms)


  Rendered devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_nav.html.erb (75.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20182ms (Views: 19855.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started GET "/campings/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-28 14:07:08 +0200
Processing by CampingsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mCamping Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "campings".* FROM "campings" WHERE "campings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mProprietaire Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "proprietaires".* FROM "proprietaires" WHERE "proprietaires"."id" = ? ORDER BY "proprietaires"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering campings/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mCaracteristiquetest Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "caracteristiquetests".* FROM "caracteristiquetests" WHERE "caracteristiquetests"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered campings/_form.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Rendered campings/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (61.0ms)
  Rendered devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered devise/menu/_login_items.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_nav.html.erb (51.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/partials/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 487ms (Views: 463.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms) 
  Started PATCH "/campings/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-28 14:07:18 +0200
Processing by CampingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1H6bsZ6d5Z8HVa0X8hUp0LQUg+SdU6CmqUEIrP7eSip0f3yVnzKlaPojwYz+AGS9a4wz4LtVeZU10G70TEIt2g==", "camping"=>{"name"=>"DOMAINE DE LA NOUE DES ROIS", "adresse"=>"rue machin", "code_postale"=>"10100", "commune"=>"ma commune", "courriel"=>"email@email.com", "site_internet"=>"www.exemple.com", "tel"=>"0101010101", "description"=>"ma description", "etoile"=>"3", "piscine"=>"Non"}, "commit"=>"Enregistrer", "id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mCamping Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "campings".* FROM "campings" WHERE "campings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mProprietaire Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "proprietaires".* FROM "proprietaires" WHERE "proprietaires"."id" = ? ORDER BY "proprietaires"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: piscine
Completed 400 Bad Request in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: caracteristiquetest):

app/controllers/campings_controller.rb:111:in `camping_params'
app/controllers/campings_controller.rb:82:in `block in update'
app/controllers/campings_controller.rb:81:in `update'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (1753.1ms)
```

**EDIT2**

I added attr_accessor :piscine on camping.rb but i have same error

---

**EDIT3**
I add this on my controller

```
(... :image, caracteristiquetest_attributes: [:piscine, :barbecue])
```

But I have always Always unpermitted paramter :piscine

development.log

```
  Started PATCH "/campings/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-28 17:24:27 +0200
    Processing by CampingsController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I7otqLV4d8oqWdCncp5yeZK1tX/NeijUMHpA+XtH+zGDu8qMtNc3PdcvvDx+iz8UTS0Fe+t88ees6yahyducwQ==", "camping"=>{"name"=>"nomducamp", "adresse"=>"adresse1", "code_postale"=>"10100", "commune"=>"SAINT-HILAIRE-SOUS-ROMILLY", "courriel"=>"mail@mail.com", "site_internet"=>"www.example.com", "tel"=>"0101010101", "description"=>"desc", "etoile"=>"3", "piscine"=>"Non renseigné"}, "commit"=>"Enregistrer", "id"=>"1"}
      [1m[36mCamping Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "campings".* FROM "campings" WHERE "campings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      [1m[36mProprietaire Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "proprietaires".* FROM "proprietaires" WHERE "proprietaires"."id" = ? ORDER BY "proprietaires"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    Unpermitted parameter: piscine
      [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
      [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/campings/1
    Completed 302 Found in 579ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

What can i do ? I m lost...

Comment: Please add the contents of the params hash as reported by your `development.log` when performing such a request.

Comment: Please add the exact error message you get. (What are the unpermitted keys?)

Comment: Also, note that `params.permit` does not actually modify the params hash. It just returns a similar hash with different access permissions. (Likewise for `params.require`.) So the first line in your `camping_params` does not have any effect.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I edited my question with log error.

Comment: add `attr_accessor :piscine ` on `camping.rb` file.

Comment: added but i have the same error => param is missing or the value is empty: caracteristiquetest

Comment: @Raffael has made two excellent comments, I'll add that you're not showing *enough* of your development.log... show it from the POST / PUT line onwards.   And your `camping_params` method makes no sense... you can't have two diffrent `params.permit` lines, only the second one will be returned.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn i edited my post with full log error. If i cant have two params.permit what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first thanks for all your comment, help. 
I find the solution with you

First in controller

```
caracteristiquetest_attributes: [:piscine, :barbecue]
```

In form

```
<%= f.fields_for :caracteristiquetest do |builder| %>
<%= builder.select(:piscine, [['Non renseigné',"Non renseigné"], ['Oui',"Oui"], ['Non',"Non"]], {:selected => (@camping.caracteristiquetest.piscine?)}, {class:"form-control", id:"exampleSelect1"}) %>
  <% end %>
```

Now thats work proprietaire can update. But i have another question :)

I have try paramaters "Unkown", "Yes", "No". For exemple i edit to choose "Yes", i see "Yes" after update. So ok. 
But when i re-edit i see the first choice "Unknown" and not the current choice "Yes" in editor. What is the solution to fix this ?

Comment: In regards to your follow up question, I have a couple of clarifying questions: 1. Do you mean just when you render the form to edit, it shows all the other camp's attributes correctly, except the piscine field, which shows "Unknown"(instead of "Yes")? If so, why does the .selected => (@camping.characteristiquetest.piscine?) have a question mark at the end of piscine? The use of a question mark on a method conventionally returns a Boolean. I would think that dropping the question mark should return the correct piscine attribute for the camp.

Comment: Also here's a the guidance for form building with select for your reference! http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models

Comment: @inveterateliterate thanks for all your comment. I deleted the "?" and all is correct. But i dont know why when I updated, form not update value from record database but he create a new records with new caracteristiquetest_id. Why he do that ?

Comment: Hm, did you say earlier it was working correctly - that when you edited from unknown to yes, it was saving the record correctly? And now instead of update its creating? Can you share your models and controller?

Comment: Yes thats it, save correctly. I just want update existing record i dont want to create a new record when i edit existing For controller [link](https://github.com/nicolaswecandoit/campsite/blob/master/app/controllers/campings_controller.rb) and model [link](https://github.com/nicolaswecandoit/campsite/blob/master/app/models/camping.rb)

Comment: I usually set the instance variable as the first line in both my edit and update methods (e.g. @camping = Camping.find(params[:id]). Maybe that should work?

Comment: @inveterateliterate unfornutually no. This method dont work. I cant update   record. After save, records still the same :/

Answer (score 1):

To pass nested attributes (e.g., another model's attributes), you can pass it as a hash in the same permit statement:

(... :image, caracteristiquetest_attributes: [:piscine, :barbecue])

Comment: Thanks @inveterateliterate for this comment. I have always unpermitted params (look my edit3)... I m lost...